How to handle the Exceptions which are thrown by org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException
How to hanlde the GenericFileOperatioFailedException and java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:it is been thrown by the apachecamel not able to handle throw my code, how to handle all the exception  which are thrown by the apache camel, not able to handle throw onException Method.
I have added the onException method in the Class which extends the Routebuilder but not able to handle the Exception still it is throwing in my console, my scenario is after the file is processed im getting the Exception not able to hanlde in mycode, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue
